# how to count similar value object in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON structure:

```
[{
    "name": "ankit",
    "DOB": "23/06"
}, {
    "name": "kapil",
    "DOB": "26/06"
}, {
    "name": "ankit",
    "DOB": "27/06"
}]
```

I want to count similar object with value `ankit`. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to loop through to all objects in your array and check for name 'ankit'

Comment: @NenadVracar if there are two object with 'ankit' than i want to count it and show it on console.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
let a = [
    { "name": "ankit", "DOB": "23/06" }, 
    { "name": "kapil", "DOB": "26/06" }, 
    { "name": "ankit", "DOB": "27/06" }
];

let count = 0;
a.forEach(item => {
    if (item.name === "ankit") {
        count++;
    }
});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%09%7B%20%22name%22%3A%20%22ankit%22%2C%20%22DOB%22%3A%20%2223%2F06%22%20%7D%2C%20%0D%0A%09%7B%20%22name%22%3A%20%22kapil%22%2C%20%22DOB%22%3A%20%2226%2F06%22%20%7D%2C%20%0D%0A%09%7B%20%22name%22%3A%20%22ankit%22%2C%20%22DOB%22%3A%20%2227%2F06%22%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20count%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Aa.forEach(item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(item.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22ankit%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09count%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(count)%3B%20%2F%2F%202))

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var count = json.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name == 'ankit';
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to reduce the items that have the name `ankit` to a number.

```js
var items = [
  {
    name: 'ankit',
    DOB: '23/06'
  },
  {
    name: 'kapil',
    DOB: '26/06'
  },
  {
    name: 'ankit',
    DOB: '27/06'
  }
]
    
var numItems = items.reduce(function (count, item) {
  return item.name === 'ankit' ? count + 1 : count
}, 0)

document.write('Number of items with the name `ankit`: ' + numItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for counting and get the wanted count for a name with the name as property.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "ankit", "DOB": "23/06" }, { "name": "kapil", "DOB": "26/06" }, { "name": "ankit", "DOB": "27/06" }],
    count = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.name] = (count[a.name] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
console.log(count['ankit']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Get the object from `JSON`:**

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

**2. Get your array filtered:**

```
var count = obj.filter(function(obj) { return obj.name == "ankit" }).length;
```